# pydev importerror: no module named thread, debugging no longer works after pydev upgrade

Tags: python, eclipse, pydev

My Eclipse 3.6 /PyDev setup just did a pydev upgrade to 1.6.0.2010071813 and debugging no longer works. My default python interpreter is 3.1 although I doubt that matters. Until the Eclipse upgrade of pydev, it was working very nicely.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This is already fixed in the current nightly (1.6.1). See: http://pydev.org/download.html for details on getting it.

Note that you can just change that "import thread" locally (in org.python.pydev.debug/pysrc/pydevd.py) for:

```
try:    
    import thread 
except ImportError:
    import _thread as thread #Py3K changed it.
```

Cheers,

Fabio

Comment: Because it's not meant to be used externally (it's the foundation for the threading module), so, it was renamed on Python 3 to reflect that (as Python 3 didn't care about backward compatibility -- and thus broke all existing Python 2 code).

Answer (score 1):

Downgrade to 1.5.9. Eclipse updates has the option to show all versions, but by default it shows only the latest version. Turn off that setting, and install 1.5.9. It works with python 3.1

Comment: You forgot to file a bug on this so I added it at https://sourceforge.net/tracker/?func=detail&aid=3035978&group_id=85796&atid=577329

Answer (score 0):

Same problem here, I am on MacOs 10.6. I tried to reinitialize the configured interpreters, it did not fix the problem. I switched between the built-in Python 2.6 and the newer 2.6.5 provided by MacPorts, this also did not fix it. Looks like it needs another update?

Update: I just tried the same upgrade on Linux (this time with a backup of the Eclipse setup :-) ), and experienced the same problem. It is not a platform issue on Mac.