# No module named 'ASWBXML'

Tags: python, centos, mitmproxy

i try to run mitmproxy on centos 6.8. so i compiled python 3.5.1 and installed ist. when i run "mitmproxy" i always get import errors.
i found a solution for: thread, cookie, cookielib...

but how to solve this problem:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/bin/mitmproxy", line 9, in <module>
   load_entry_point('mitmproxy==0.15', 'console_scripts', 'mitmproxy')()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/libmproxy/main.py", line 41, in mitmproxy
    from . import console
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/libmproxy/console/__init__.py", line 17, in <module>
    from .. import controller, flow, script, contentviews
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/libmproxy/flow.py", line 16, in <module>
    from . import controller, tnetstring, filt, script, version, flow_format_compat
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/libmproxy/script/__init__.py", line 2, in <module>
    from .script_context import ScriptContext
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/libmproxy/script/script_context.py", line 5, in <module>
    from .. import contentviews
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/libmproxy/contentviews.py", line 32, in <module>
    from .contrib.wbxml.ASCommandResponse import ASCommandResponse
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/libmproxy/contrib/wbxml/ASCommandResponse.py", line 30, in <module>
    from ASWBXML import ASWBXML
ImportError: No module named 'ASWBXML'
```

Comment: have you tried `pip install ASWBXML` ?

Comment: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement ASWBXML (from versions: )
No matching distribution found for ASWBXML

Comment: You are using mitmproxy 0.17, which does not support Python 3.5 yet: http://stackoverflow.com/a/36871976 Our next release will support 3.5, due in a few days :)